# SharePoint designer workflow to copy a list item to another list which includes a lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, copy-item

I have a need to merge 2 SharePoint lists into a third list.  I'm using the copy item command in SharePoint designer.  I've also tried the create item command.

Both work well until I get to a lookup field.  The lookup field doesn't copy.  I tried creating a  local variable but that doesn't work either.

I'm using SharePoint Designer 2013 for an Office 365 implementation.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I switched to a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow, I could capture the lookup fields properly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/68244)

Comment: Yes, actually it does answer the question.  I wasn't able to see the lookup fields when using a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow.  When I switched to a 2010 workflow it works fine.